# External USB-camera opencv. Img oversaturated

Tags: python, opencv

I am working with opencv v.'4.4.0' in python 3.7 and whenever I get images from an external USB camera, this ones are oversaturated. How can I control the adjust the brighness parameter for the img capture?

The camera is an external USB camera from Microsoft 1080p HD Sensor.

Below the code and img sample.

```
import cv2
import numpy

def get_img_camera(): #return frame (img)

    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # 1 laptop camera, 0 external camera
    cam.set(3,1280)
    cam.set(4,720)

    cv2.namedWindow("Plates")

    while True:
        ret, frame = cam.read()
        rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

        scale = 1.0  # opacity out of 100%
        frame_darker = (frame * scale).astype(numpy.uint8)
        #cam = frame_darker

        if not ret:
            print("failed to grab frame")
            break
        #cv2.imshow("Image", frame)

        #k = cv2.waitKey(0)

        img_name = "img_from_camera.jpg"
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame_darker)
        print("{} written!".format(img_name))
        break

    cam.release()

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    return frame

get_img_camera()
```

[View Img capture: oversaturated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDut2.jpg)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try the ApiPreference which preferred Capture API backends to use. Can be used to enforce a specific reader implementation if multiple are available.(https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html)

```
#capture from camera at location 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

```
#Brightness (0-100)
cap.set(10,100)
```

```
#Sturation (0-100)
cap.set(12,100)
```

Those functions are work to me, worth to try. And make sure your python and opencv version are not too old.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried and it does not improves the image. However, I also tried the camera in a another app, and it also have the same output. I believe either the camera is defective, or I need a driver or something.

Comment: Thank you. After making further test, I replaces the camera and the problem was solved. Apparently there was a compatibility issue with the camera model and Mac OS.